# How to write NFC tag that will launch browser offline and display html?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I want to build a NFC writer app that will write short html to a tag. When read, it will send the html to a browser (chrome, or whatever the user chooses) and display it. No internet connection whatsoever. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: I have done an app like this but I didnt got 1 thing please clear me that . You want to load the HTML in offline mode ?

Comment: yes, i want to load the html offline. I know you can send a URL, but I would like to send html. The only way I see of doing this is to write a file with the html on the device, and then send the URI to the browswer. But I don't this the OS would let a NFC tag write files to disk.

Comment: I dnt know exactly how to load that offline. But once I created an html in text file and kept it in my raw folder and loaded the content

Comment: If u need to show that way in web view I can help you

Comment: Thanks, but it's really the offline html from NFC that I need help with. :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a tag of MIME-type text/html; if a browser is configured to respond to that tag, it should respond to the intent. You'd have to check the manifest for your browser(s) to see whether or not that is supported, however. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html)